# Windows migration tool

Tags: windows-xp, backup, installation, migration

I want a program which can help me with reinstalling the system. I want to save the settings of programs installed on my system. The settings of my user profile. Create backup of my directories. I know about [USMT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_State_Migration_Tool) but can USMT 3.0 help me if I want to save settings of Oracle client and other non-Microsoft applications?

Comment: can you give more information?  Is this a new system you are building?  Cleaning the old system?  Updating windows?  What is the purpose and goal of this?  When I do a new system I just start from scratch gives it a new feel for a new system.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, I know a tool called Migwiz.
It works on Windows XP and it allows you to migrate your settings and all.
It's now built in into Vista and 7, but not on XP.
You can build the archive from XP and install it on 7 (I'm not sure but it should work). I know this operation works on Vista.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/928634